# Incorrect display with JSF, JBOSS

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got this strange problem in JBOSS 6, Eclipse, JSF MOJARRA.

So this is my index.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     >

    <!-- 
        Replace path to template, title, header and body
        with actual data.
     -->
    <h:head>
        <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - hello.xhtml</h3>
        <h:form>
           <h:inputText value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
           <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

In the execution I've got only the title of the page, no input text, no button.
Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks your page cannot be parsed. You should check your faces-config.xml if it has this line of code

```
 < view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler< /view-handler>
```

(erase spaces)  and your lib must have jsf-facelets.jar .